# How can I skip the NSIS "components" page?

Tags: user-interface, components, usability, nsis

I'm using NSIS to create the installer (with the "Modern" UI) for a Java application that only has one installable component. It seems silly to show the user the "components" page in this scenario. How can I suppress that page? I tried commenting it out in my script as follows:

```
...
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "..\..\..\src\main\nsis\Readme.txt"
;!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
...
```

But that led to all sorts of scary warnings (although the installer does seem to work):

```
[MAKENSIS] warning: unknown variable/constant "mui.ComponentsPage.DescriptionText" detected, ignoring (macro:MUI_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN:4)
[MAKENSIS] warning: unknown variable/constant "mui.ComponentsPage.DescriptionText" detected, ignoring (macro:MUI_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN:5)
[MAKENSIS] warning: unknown variable/constant "mui.ComponentsPage.DescriptionText.Info" detected, ignoring (macro:MUI_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN:6)
[MAKENSIS] warning: unknown variable/constant "mui.ComponentsPage.DescriptionText" detected, ignoring (macro:MUI_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN:6)
[MAKENSIS] warning: unknown variable/constant "mui.ComponentsPage.DescriptionText" detected, ignoring (macro:MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT:6)
[MAKENSIS] warning: unknown variable/constant "mui.ComponentsPage.DescriptionText" detected, ignoring (macro:MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT:7)
[MAKENSIS] warning: unknown variable/constant "mui.ComponentsPage.DescriptionText" detected, ignoring (macro:MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT:8)
```

I found an [NSIS wiki entry about skipping pages](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Skipping_Pages), but couldn't make head nor tail of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove the component description macro's from your script (MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN, MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT, MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_END)

Comment: That did it, thanks! As a new NSIS user, I had no idea that those macros had anything to do with the components page; it's certainly not self-evident.

Comment: Well, the text you assign there is only visible on the components page, AND the fact that the warnings begin with mui.ComponentsPage =)